# How to make Usercontrol behave differently for different pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have an aspx user control which i use in two different pages. I have a "save" button in usercontrol page and when it gets clicked it has to store data in db. But the data is to be stored in different tables based on the page. The question is how to make the save button event of the user control to behave differently based on the pages that using the usercontrol.
And also the heading and some css classes must be different for different pages. How to check for the css classes also for different pages.

Comment: Make a custom event in the user-control. Raise the event when _Save_ is clicked. Let the different pages handle the event and save in their ways.

Comment: .. or provide a property for user control, to be set by different pages, to control *how* the `Save` button will works.

Comment: Ya,Custom event is the best way i think... What to do for css classes in the page.

Comment: for css class or heading, follow Sinatr's advice. Create a string property in the user-control and let the pages set appropriate values for css-class/header. Use that property to set header/css-class in the  user-control.

Answer (score 3):

[It's possible](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/16/creatingsetting-properties-of-user-control-in-aspnet) to define property TableName in UserControl class:

```
public string TableName { get; set; }
```

set it where the control is used:

```
<uc:MyControl runat="Server" ID="MyControl1" TableName="Foo" />
<uc:MyControl runat="Server" ID="MyControl2" TableName="Bar" />
```

and use it in the event handler as any other .NET property:

```
protected void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tableName = TableName;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks that works!!
 Public Property FunctionPerpose() As String
        Get
            Return m_FunctionPerpose
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_FunctionPerpose = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FunctionPerpose As String

```
Private Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    If FunctionPerpose = "PurificationImport" Then
        MessageBox.Show("File uploaded successfully")
    ElseIf FunctionPerpose = "XYZImport" Then
```

end if
end sub

build this user control and you can see this new FunctionPerpose property in properties window at right side where you are using that user control